# How to mix url string & attribute value in CSS content property?

Tags: html, css

I need to show image corresponding to each item beside it, using CSS `content` property & `:before` pseudo selector.

How do I do something like below in a valid working way:

```
content: url("http://example.com/images/" + attr(title));
```

to show an image at URL

```
 "http://example.com/images/523452345"
```

The above does not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do that, this is the specification, you can't place attr() inside url(), they can only follow each other.

```
content: normal | none | 
         [ <string> | <uri> | <counter> | attr() |
           open-quote | close-quote | no-open-quote | no-close-quote ]+ | inherit


div:before {
    content: url("http://example.com/image.jpg") attr(title);
}
```